# How to move a node from the different locations?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to move a tree node to the left firstly from the center of the screen and then from the right to the left corner. It should look like infinite amount of trees. I have no problem with first part. Here is the code:

```
let tree = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "oak")
tree.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)           
self.addChild(tree)
var move = SKAction.moveToX(150, duration: 1)
tree.runAction(move)
```

But how to do a second part? The only thing I thought could work is to make another SKSpriteNode with the same image and give it another starting position.

But I feel like there must be a better solution!

I figured it out. Maybe, not elegant at all but it works!

```
func newPlace() {
    tree.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + 100, self.size.height / 2)
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    tree.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(tree)

    var move = SKAction.moveToX(150, duration: 1)
    var place = SKAction.runBlock(newPlace)
    var moveAlong = SKAction.moveToX(100, duration: 2)
    var seq = SKAction.sequence([place, moveAlong])
    var repeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq)
    var sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, place, moveAlong, seq, repeat])
    tree.runAction(sequence)

       }
```

Maybe, it will help someone.

Comment: Use action sequence with two actions. First one should move tree from point A to point B, and the second one should set node's position to point A, and then just repeat that sequence forever. For second task you can use SKAction.runBlock({ ...}) to change node's position..

Comment: As I understood I need to make a function somewhere. And in this function I declare a new position of the tree node. And then I put this function in `runBlock`. Am I right? Also, additional question if you don't mind – how can I manage an interval between those trees? I would like to make it more of a random thing but in some range. But, that's fine if I just could hardcore a few positions for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using Swift at all, but this simple example should explain how to move sprite from one side to the other side of a screen and make all looks endless:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let tree = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor .greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20,30))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        println(self.frame.size)

        tree.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + self.tree.size.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        var move = SKAction.moveToX(-tree.size.width, duration: 3)
        var reset = SKAction.runBlock(){
            self.tree.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width+self.tree.size.width, y: self.tree.position.y)
        }


        var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5) //  Here you can randomize. This will make animation to wait before starts

        var sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,move,reset])

        self.tree.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))

        self.addChild(tree)

    }

}
```

I assume your scene's dimensions are set correctly so when you copy/paste and run this code you should see desired results (it works for me). About randomizing between two numbers search SO site, there are a lot of post describing that topic.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've helped me a lot. But what is SO site? I don't think I know that one.

Comment: SO == StackOverflow ... And you are welcome, I am glad it helped.